# Selenium Java - How To Find Element That Dynamically Changes Type?

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing tests for a login page using Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse.
The password field on the login page is first loaded as a text field (passwordText) for security reasons. But when the user places the cursor into username or password field the password field type is changed to password (password) using javascript.

The problem is my Selenium test cannot find the password field. It comes back with an error 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"password"}'

This is the code I am using:

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/login");
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username1");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("mypassword");
```

How can I write the code to correctly find the password field?

Comment: Does the element's identity remain the same when the JavaScript code changes its type? Would you be able to obtain a reference to it before placing the cursor in it, and use that same reference to enter the text?

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your comment. It has helped point me in the right direction and answer the question. I will add the answer now for anyone else who encounters this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the answer and will add it here for anyone else with a similar issue.

The resolution was to first find the field by its first id - passwordText and then sendKeys to the field using the id it has changed to after cursor focus - password.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username1");
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordText")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("mypassword");
```